# getting Selenium NameError on launching appium ruby console

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rubygems, appium

I am getting the error on launching appium ruby console

> uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::COMMANDS
>   (NameError)

I am using latest selenium webdriver

Comment: specific to mac and appium ruby console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this error resolved by upgrading appium_lib to appium_lib-8.0.0 on appium

`cd appium
gem uninstall -aIx appium_lib 
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri appium_lib`

Comment: this issue will not come on new appium version